# My site's background isn't loading correctly on mobile browsers

Tags: browser, mobile, background

Not sure why, but my the background on my site isn't loading (or, when it occasionally does, it's taking forever) on mobile browsers.  I've tested it on both an iPhone 4S and an iPad 2.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?  The problem started happening out of nowhere.

The site is http://fanbeat.com.

Thanks.

Comment: Your background image is huge (130kb) maybe the mobile browsers are opting to not download it or deprioritizing it.

Comment: For what its worth I just checked on my android your background appears just fine on Android Browser and Opera Mobile.

Comment: Yeah, it's bigger than I'd like it to be.  Any suggestions for correcting that without sacrificing quality?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server is quite slow.  On my cable internet connection (desktop computer mind you) it took 1.5s to download, which is crazy for a 130Kb file.

[image]

Here's a smaller version of your background image to try.  It's only 40K.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm temporarily hosting the launch page on GoDaddy since there isn't much going on.  Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  That pageload time is pretty bad for such a simple, small page.  If it takes 1.5s to load a 130Kb file, they have seriously oversold your server.  I would expect more like 300-400ms based on my connection to other servers with similar sized files (tested just now).  As Max pointed out, you could temporarily work around the problem by reducing the size of that file.  I'll update my answer to include a smaller version of your background image.

Comment: Any preference between AWS and Rackspace?

Comment: Thanks for providing that smaller image. I'd actually been trying that approach, but for some reason the background isn't tiling together seamlessly.  I have a feeling it's because of the noise on the texture, but I'm trying to figure a way to keep that.

Comment: No problem.  I've updated the image again leaving it at the full original width (100px) but still a much smaller file size (40K).  Let me know if there is anything else I can help with.  Otherwise it would be greatly appreciated if you could mark my answer as **Accepted** and maybe upvote it if you feel it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I marked that it was helpful, but I can't yet upvote because my reputation isn't yet high enough.  I'll do my best to remember to return and upvote your answer once my reputation score hits 15.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you, no problem.  You should be able to mark it as accepted though - just click the checkmark arrow underneath the up/down icons.  It will cause it to turn green and offically mark this as the "accepted" answer.  It will also give you a couple extra points to help your own reputation by marking it as Accepted!

Comment: @Max I think I realized the problem -- you should mark the overall answer as accepted, and not one of my comments.  :)